# "table or view does not exist"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create some tables but i get every time i try `table or view does not exist.`

I cant find any solution. Here is my code.

```
 CREATE
  TABLE "User"
  (
    anon_id      NUMBER (38) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    querytime    TIMESTAMP ,
    state_symbol VARCHAR2 (5) NOT NULL
  ) ;

CREATE
  TABLE "state"
  (
    symbol            VARCHAR2 (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name              VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) ,
    "size"            NUMBER (38) ,
    population        NUMBER (38) ,
    tourists          NUMBER (38) 
  ) ;

CREATE
  TABLE "population_goup"
  (
    name              VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    COUNT             NUMBER (38) 
  ) ;
```

The first 3 tables are createt and now he starts "table or view does not exist" and i dont know why.

```
CREATE TABLE "location"
  (
    zip         NUMBER (38) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    city        VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    state_symbol VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    timezone    VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    latitude    FLOAT ,
    longitude   FLOAT ,
    population  NUMBER (38) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (state_symbol) references state(symbol)
  ) ;

CREATE
  TABLE landmark
  (
    name              VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    tourists          NUMBER (38) NOT NULL ,
    location_zip      NUMBER (38) NOT NULL REFERENCES location (zip)
  ) ;


CREATE
  TABLE event
  (
    name              VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL ,
    from_date         TIMESTAMP ,
    to_date           TIMESTAMP ,
    location_zip      NUMBER (38) NOT NULL REFERENCES location (zip)
  ) ;


CREATE
  TABLE lives_in
  (
    population_goup_name VARCHAR2 (255) NOT NULL REFERENCES population_group(NAME),
    state_symbol         VARCHAR2 (5) NOT NULL REFERENCES state(SYMBOL),
    PRIMARY KEY(population_goup_name, state_symbol)
  ) ;

  CREATE
  TABLE "searchquery"
  (
    query        VARCHAR2 (4000 CHAR) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    User_id NUMBER (38) NOT NULL REFERENCES User(anon_id),
    state_symbol VARCHAR2 (5) REFERENCES state(symbol),
    population_name VARCHAR2 (255) REFERENCES population_goup(name),
    landmark_name  VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) REFERENCES landmark(name),
    event_name  VARCHAR2 (255) REFERENCES event(name),
    location_zip NUMBER (38) REFERENCES landmark(zip)
  ) ;
```

For searchquery i get "invalid table name" but its not a reserved word so why?
I cant find any help from the script of my uni so i thanks to every one that can help me!

Comment: case sensitive object names and objects using reserved words as names are both recipes for unintended consequences if not disaster down the line at some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order, every object is saved with **UPPER CASE** name. Unless enclosed within **double quotes**.

Remove the double quotes to all your table names in the `DDL`. Also, User, State all are reserved keywords. You cannot use them as table names.

`"state"` --> `state`

OR

Refer your tables in the constraints with double quotes, same as in DDL previously..

`references state(symbol)` --> `references "state"(symbol)`

> `searchquery` DDL ended with invalid table name because, you refer
>   User table, which is a `datadictionary` table. So, embed them in
>   double quotes

**Example:**

```
CREATE
  TABLE "searchquery"
  (
    query        VARCHAR2 (4000 CHAR) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    User_id NUMBER (38) NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"(anon_id),
    state_symbol VARCHAR2 (5) REFERENCES "state"(symbol),
    population_name VARCHAR2 (255) REFERENCES "population_goup"(name),
    landmark_name  VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) REFERENCES "landmark"(name),
    event_name  VARCHAR2 (255) REFERENCES "event"(name),
    location_zip NUMBER (38) REFERENCES "landmark"(zip)
  ) ;
```

From DOCs.

> Nonquoted identifiers are not case sensitive. Oracle interprets them
>   as uppercase. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive.
>
> By enclosing names in double quotation marks, you can give the
>   following names to different objects in the same namespace:
>
> employees 
> "employees"
>   "Employees"
>
> Note that Oracle interprets the following names the same, so they
>   cannot be used for different objects in the same namespace:
>
> employees 
>  EMPLOYEES 
>  "EMPLOYEES"

[More on the Schema Object Names and Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)

Comment: Thanks you are right but did you know why searchquery is a invalid table name?

Comment: Apparently there is an issue with the examples in the manual. Both lists  include `employees` and `"EMPLOYEES"`, effectively saying first that those names are different and then that they are identical. As far as I understand, only the second statement is correct.

Comment: I removed the "" and he still tells me invalid table name for searchquery

Comment: @The8Monkey the problem is referring the User table, I added the exact DDL to answer.

Answer (score 1):

`state` is a keyword, so you double quoted it to use it as a table name. Now you need the quoted name whenever you access that table:

```
CREATE TABLE "location"
  (
    zip         NUMBER (38) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    city        VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    state_symbol VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    timezone    VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
    latitude    FLOAT ,
    longitude   FLOAT ,
    population  NUMBER (38) NOT NULL ,
    FOREIGN KEY (state_symbol) references "state"(symbol)
  ) ;
```